# How to get the PrinterDiscoverySession when using the printer in android 4.4

Tags: android, printing, android-print-framework

I am recently using the Printing Framework in Android 4.4, now I have a demand to get the printer's information which can be used in the Mobile phone or tablet.

I found the [PrinterDiscoverySession](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/printservice/PrinterDiscoverySession.html) class contains the printer's information. But how can I get the instance of the PrinterDiscoverySession class?

Comment: Hi Lee, Did you find any solution?. Please let me know. I also have same requirement.

Answer (score 3):

Seems like the Android printing API hides the printer details to the regular apps. Only a [PrintService](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/printservice/PrintService.html) has this knowledge, but a PrintService is made to let other apps print: it doesn't print anything by itself - it's like a printer driver in the PC world.

The PrinterDiscoverySession is an abstract class implemented by a PrintService; it tells the PrintService when it's time to scan for the available printers in the network (wifi, bluetooth, cable, this is up to the PrintService implementation) and to report back the list of printers found. This list is only used by Android and its system activities, but never (AFAIK) shared with the apps.